# Vertical bars distortion on video streamed live with Flash and Red5

Tags: flash, video, webcam, red5

I have a Red5 streaming with flash recorder & player. I use H.264 encoder for streaming video. But there is some issue which have about 20% people, those bars appear on a video:

[image]

How to get rid of that bars ? I tried to create .swf with lot of different settings and target flash player version. As you can see those bars doesn't seem to be compressed, so maybe this is the player issue, not recorder ? Issue is connected to specified stream, I mean that if a stream has those bars, then every other player (watcher of that specified stream) will also have this kind of distortion.

Comment: (1) Do the bars move?
(2) Is the image behind the bar distorted - tilted sideways or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say why you get this or how to fix it, but I'm pretty sure I could tell *what* it is.  This looks like a very characteristic type of bug in which the image is stored as a 1D array with a certain stride (distance to advance in the 1D array to go to the next row) but it is being processed or displayed with a different stride, resulting in each successive row being offset horizontally by the same amount relative to the previous row.  Stride in general may not be equal to width of the video, and confusion between the two is a common type of bug in video software.  The luminance (grayscale) plane (part of the image) seems to have the correct stride here, but the chroma (color) planes of the video have been processed with incorrect stride.  The green areas look like they have have chroma values of U=0 and V=0 in the YUV colorspace (ie they probably came from the padding between rows), and we see color stairstepping for all colors identical to the stairstepping green areas.

Comment: is right, this is a stride issue. If the bars are moving across the screen it is a stride issue. It could also be caused by a chroma format issue yuv420 being accessed as yuv422 but I can't tell that with confidence wihtout seeing the video.

Answer (score 0):

your statement:

```
I mean that if a stream has those bars, then every other player (watcher of that specified stream) will also have this kind of distortion.
```

=> that sounds for me basically like a webcam issue. 
Did you try to publish the stream with standard settings too? I mean instead of h264 with the Sorensen Codec.
Do those issues happen with Sorensen Codec too?
Cause basically your issue sounds like a problem when the video is created in the sender side.
Red5 does nothing else then proxying the stream to all participants.

Sebastian

Comment: I don't think that it is a webcam/H.264 issue, because i saw another site when same person has not this distortion on video. This site also based on Flash & Red5 with H.264 encoding in flash recorder (i check decompiled source and H.264 profile and settings was the same)

Comment: I would suggest you might try to use the oflaDemo and recorder app that are provided as demo application with Red5. If the same webcam runs perfectly smooth with the demo apps it should run fine with your application too.